# node.js storing previous form data, and rerunning previous mysql queries every time form is submitted with new data

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, callback

I am having a problem with node.js where every time I run a query, it reruns all the previous queries ran, along with the new one.

More specifically: I have a form with three fields: first name, last name, email. When I submit that form, I want to:
 - check if the user already exists in the database (I do this with a SQL query on the email address).
 - if client exists, display a message on the form that the client can't be added.
 - if the user DOESN't exists, add the client to the database and display a 'Successfully added client' message on the form.

Seems easy, right?

What is happening is that for the first new user I add, everything is fine. Then I add a second new user, but what happens in the database is that it adds TWO entries: it re-adds the first new user, and the second as well. If I try to add a third user, it ends up running 3 'INSERT INTO' queries, adding the first user (a third time) and the second user again, then the third. And so on...

It's like there is some storage somewhere that I am not clearing out between form submissions - but I'm not using a session here, so I don't know where this form data is being persisted!

Any thoughts? I am very new to node.js and I think I must be missing something very fundamental, but I can't see it.

Here is the javascript and form from my 'index.html' file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#new_client").submit(function(){
            var form = $(this);

            //remove previous message section
            form.siblings('p').remove();

            $.getJSON(
                form.attr('action'),
                form.serialize(),
                function (result){
                    if (result.success == true){
                        $(form).before("<p>Success: "+result.message+"</p>");
                    }
                    else if (result.success == false){
                        var html = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.message.length; i++){
                            html += "<p>Failed: "+result.message[i]+"</p>";
                        }
                        $(form).before(html);
                    } 
                }); //end $.getJSON

             return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <form id="new_client" action="/add_client" method="get">
    <!-- NOTE: we need to use method="get" for getJSON -->
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Client first name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Client last name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Client email">
        <button type="submit">Add Client</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

And here are parts of my nodejs code (server.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var events = require('events');
var Validator = require('validator').Validator;
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var db = mysql.createConnection({
   //host:'localhost',
   port: 8889,
   user: 'root',
   password: 'root',
   database: 'test_database'
});

server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
var pageUrl = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

if(pageUrl === '/add_client'){
    var dataQuery = url.parse(request.url).query;
    var formData = querystring.parse(dataQuery);

    //set up event listener for 'add client result'
    eventEmitter.on('addClientResult', function (result){
        response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });

        //set up listener for existing client check
        eventEmitter.on('clientIsNewResult', function (result){
            if (result.success === false){
            response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
            else {
                //this will trigger the 'addClientResult' event
                addClient(db, formData.first_name, formData.last_name, formData.email);
            }
        });

        //set up event listener for validated data
        eventEmitter.on('validateDataResult', function (result){
            if (result.success === false)
                response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
            else{
                //trigger 'clientIsNewResult' event
                clientIsNew(db, formData.email);
            }
        });

        // trigger the validateDataResult event
        validateData(formData.first_name, formData.last_name, formData.email);

    } //end 'add_client'
    else { ... code for other actions and where we start the response object... }
}); //end of server object

server.listen(8080);

function clientIsNew(db, email){
    db.query('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email=?', [email],
        function (errors, results, fields) {
            if (errors) throw errors;

                //console.log(this.sql);
                if (results.length > 0){
                    query_result = {
                        'success': false,
                        'message': ['There is already a client with this email address!']
                }
            }
            else {
                query_result = {
                    'success': true,
                    'message': 'This is a unique user'
                };
            }

            eventEmitter.emit('clientIsNewResult', query_result);
    });
}
function addClient(db, first_name, last_name, email){
    //the only time we should get here is when we want to create a new user
    //so we should only get here when 'clientIsNewResult' is triggered and gets
    // a result of true... at least that is the intention!
    db.query('INSERT INTO clients SET first_name=?, last_name=?, email=?, created_at=NOW();',
        [first_name, last_name, email],
        function (errors, results, fields) {
            if (errors) throw errors;

            //console.log(this.sql);
            insert_result = {
                'success': true,
                'message': 'Client is added'
            }

            eventEmitter.emit('addClientResult', insert_result);
        }
    );
}

function validateData(first_name, last_name, email){
... validates info, no problems with this ...

    eventEmitter.emit('validateDataResult', result);
}

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

OK, I hope that wasn't too much, I deleted a lot of comments and other console.log lines I had in there as well.

Please let me know if I need to post more, or less, or if I've forgotten something.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got some guidance from a mentor. My problem is that every time I send data to the server, I am creating another event listener, but the previous event listener(s) still exist. So the second time I submitted the form, there were two event listeners on the same event; the third time, there were three... ect.

Solution: major refactor of code, to not use so many. ALSO: changing `eventEmitter.on()` to `eventEmitter.once()` for the addClientResult event, which is the only event listener left. After all, I only want to add a client once each time I submit data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Move you Event emitter to inside you http request

move

```
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

to

```
server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
var pageUrl = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I think it introduces a scope issue. If I move the eventEmitter to inside the Server, I get a syntax error, `ReferenceError: eventEmitter is not defined` and the line given is in the validateData function, this line: `eventEmitter.emit('validateDataResult', result);`

Comment: Try passing the eventemitter instance to the functions like 

function clientIsNew(db, email){
should be

function clientIsNew(db, email, eventemt){

Comment: I' not sure how to follow what you're saying. Do you mean do something like combining into one line like `'eventEmitter.emit('clientIsNewResult', clientIsNew(db, email));` ? I tried that as well and it didn't work.